# Packages, libraries, functions and their dependencies among each other, especially for mlr3

Tags: function, package, dependencies, libraries, mlr3

Community, I would like to understand better the economy and dependencies of packages, libraries and functions in R, especially concerning the “mlr3verse” package. When I start R in Version 4.3.2 on my Win11-64 bit System, the mentioned package is loaded in version 0.2.8 and also the package "mlr3" itself in version 0.17.0 as confirmed by the call of “installed.packages()”.

When I then subsequently run e.g. the function “tsk”, R tells: “could not find function tsk" although the named function is already available for selection in the list of suggested functions during input. The function is only available after manual reloading of the “mlr3verse” library. Why is the function "tsk" not available directly after start? Thank you for an answer.

As mentioned, I already tried to call the function "tsk" but wasn't available without loding the package “mlr3verse” manually afterwards, although the mentioned package was already loaded before by confirmation of “installed.packages()”.

Comment: Can't reproduce this; works fine for me after loading `mlr3verse`.

Comment: This is different to my experience. My system requires a manual reload of library "mlr3verse" to register the function "tsk", every time I start R new. So it seems to be a systematic issue on my environment, so I posted it.